# Serving CSS, images and JavaScript in Drupal

Tags: 7, performance

Does the whole Drupal stack get fired up (bootstrapped) each time one of these static content types gets requested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, it does not.
But if you have let's say in one of your stylesheet files a reference to a missing image, or your code is trying to load a missing js file then because of the Rewrite Rules in .htaccess this requests are redirected to index.php and that causes the bootstrapping of the whole system to render the 404 page.

Comment: How does Drupal knows the difference between a dynamic page request and a static resource request?

Comment: Apache is the one who knows the difference via rules in the [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/htaccess.html) file. If you are getting a lot of 404s for CSS/JS files might I recommend the [advagg](http://drupal.org/project/advagg) module.